# Angular dynamic form observable input property always null

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm teaching myself reactive forms in Angular and have become stuck following the [Dynamic Forms guide](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form).

In the `question.service.ts` file, I've added a delay to the returned observable to simulate a HTTP request:

```
return of(questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)).pipe(delay(10));
```

This observable is passed to the `app-dynamic-form` component in the `app-root` template:

```
<app-dynamic-form [questions]="questions$ | async"></app-dynamic-form>
```

But the `questions` input property value seems to be always null.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
>       at QuestionControlService.toFormGroup (question-control.service.ts:19)
>       at DynamicFormComponent.ngOnInit (dynamic-form.component.ts:22)

Removing the `.pipe(delay(10))` returns the example to a working state.

Can anyone explain why `questions` input property is null?

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jihunl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion.service.ts) for working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting error because input property binding is happening asynchronusly.

**Try this:**

```
    <div>
        <ng-container *ngIf="questions$ | async as questions">
         <app-dynamic-form [questions]="questions"></app-dynamic-form>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me about this: Before adding `.pipe(delay(10))` there is no delay but questions$ was always an  `observable` because of using `of`. So why can't async pipe manage it without using `*ngIf` when it is delayed?

Comment: Thanks this absolutely solves it. I've not added the container however as it seems you can do it inline: `<app-dynamic-form *ngIf="questions$ | async as questions" [questions]="questions"></app-dynamic-form>`

Comment: async pipe allows the subscription to observables inside of the angular template syntax. Before async resolve the data the component get created in the dom, that's why adding delay to it causing error. @Ramesh